# Asterisk client behind NAT - UDP registration does not work

Tags: nat, asterisk, udp, sip, avaya

I have some clients connected to my Asterisk server behind a NAT device. When using TCP everything works OK. If I change the client and server config to use UDP (from `transport=tcp` to `transport=udp,tcp` or even simply `transport=udp`) the phone can no longer register and Asterisk sends `SIP: SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized` to the client.

From what I have read it is possible to use UDP behind a NAT with Asterisk, however experience seems to dictate otherwise. Have I missed another mandatory step or is there something else that I am unaware of?

To clarify: it is the clients behind the NAT device; not the server.

Here's the relevant portions of my sip.conf:

```
[general]
context=bogus
allowguest=no
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
alwaysauthreject=yes
videosupport=yes
canreinvite=no
nat=force_rport,comedia
session-timers=refuse
localnet=x.x.x.x/255.255.0.0     ; blanked out for serverfault
tcpenable=yes                    ; Enable server for incoming TCP connections (default is no)
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0:5060         ; IP address for TCP server to bind to (0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces)
transport=udp,tcp

[my-codecs](!)                    ; a template for my preferred codecs
        disallow=all
;        allow=ilbc
;        allow=gsm
;        allow=g723
        allow=alaw
        allow=ulaw
;       allow=g722

[basic-options](!,my-codecs)                ; another template
        dtmfmode=rfc2833
        context=internal
        type=friend


[natted-phone](!,basic-options)   ; another template inheriting basic-options
        directmedia=no
        host=dynamic
        transport=tcp,udp

[101](natted-phone)
callerid="Office"
secret=12345678901234567890
context=internal
mailbox=101@main
transport=udp,tcp
```

UPDATE: On investigation I have found that this only seems to affect Avaya handsets. Other softphones connected to the same server do not seem to suffer this problem. Here is a sample of register and un authorized packets:

```
asterisk*CLI> sip set debug on
SIP Debugging enabled
<--- SIP read from UDP:x.x.x.x:1032 --->
REGISTER sip:asterisk SIP/2.0
From: sip:2003@asterisk;tag=46c2abf4589053ec5895ffc0_F2003192.168.0.174
To: sip:2003@asterisk
Call-ID: 1_5a7d0-b0875cb5895fbc0_R@192.168.0.174
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.174;branch=z9hG4bK1_5a7d12149bcad5895ffc4_R2003
Content-Length: 0
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:2003@192.168.0.174;avaya-sc-enabled;transport=udp>;q=1;expires=900;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-2cf4c54ef19b>"
Allow: INVITE,CANCEL,BYE,ACK,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,MESSAGE,INFO,PUBLISH,REFER,UPDATE
User-Agent: Avaya one-X Deskphone
Supported: eventlist

<------------->
--- (12 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to x.x.x.x:1032 (NAT)
Sending to x.x.x.x:1032 (NAT)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to x.x.x.x:1032 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.174;branch=z9hG4bK1_5a7d12149bcad5895ffc4_R2003;received=x.x.x.x;rport=1032
From: sip:2003@asterisk;tag=46c2abf4589053ec5895ffc0_F2003192.168.0.174
To: sip:2003@asterisk;tag=as5f37e30b
Call-ID: 1_5a7d0-b0875cb5895fbc0_R@192.168.0.174
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 13.1.0~dfsg-1.1ubuntu4
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="2350c222"
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Using UDP behind a NAT is entirely possible. Please provide more info about your environment. at least post [general] section of your sip.conf & configuration of that extension, which you got trouble authentificating...

Comment: For Avaya handsets you'd have to provide exact packets, which were send during authorization. You can get them in asterisk console (access by `asterisk -rvvvv`) then executing `sip set debug on` there...

Answer (score 1):

When using Asterisk behind NAT, you should always add the `externip` option along with `nat` option to the [general] section of your `sip.conf`

Try this

```
[general]
nat=force_rport,comedia
externip=<your external IP here>
... rest of your config ...
```

Some clients also allow specifying the "*Proxy Address*" field in addition to *SIP Server address* & *SIP Domain*. When using NAT you should put your external IP there. So a configuration like this should also keep you safe:

```
 SIP Server: 192.168.1.200 (Servers internal IP)
 SIP Proxy: 1.2.3.4  (Servers external IP)
 SIP Domain: 192.168.1.200  (Servers internal IP)
```

Finally, checking your asterisk logs in real time, by running:

```
 asterisk -rvvvv
```

will help you to diagnose a lot, since `401 Unauthorized` maybe related to ACL-problems (like when a peers IP doesn't match permit/deny options specified in sip.conf). In that case Asterisk will give an error like:

```
SIP Peer ACL: Rejecting '1.2.3.4' due to a failure to pass ACL '(BASELINE)'
```

P.S. This might save you a lot of headache. Always remember to forward full range of RTP ports, which are specified in `/etc/asterisk/rtp.conf`
If you have

```
rtpstart=50000
rtpend=60000
```

there, then you should unconditionally forward 50000-60000 UDP from your [external IP] to your asterisk, or you *will* face a lot of weird problems (like inability to reliably transfer a call, random voice loss/disconnections and lots of other things you definitely do not want)...

Comment: Apologies if it wasn't initially clear from the description, but it is the clients that are behind NAT, not the server. I've put a clarifier in the description now.

Answer (score -1):

This is proper behavior - you have to understand how NAT works!  NAT can only track connections by keeping a table of open connections (opened by SYN ACK, closed by FIN ACK).  But only TCP uses connections; UDP is connectionless.

So a NAT device does not even attempt to route UDP packets based on connection state.  If you need NAT traversal for UDP packets you will have to create static rules based on port range, source IP, etc.

Comment: Since the phone actually receives *401 Unauthorized* error, you can safely assume that network is configured just fine in that case. It's an asterisk-related issue - removing "fromdomain" option from extension config usually fix that ...

Comment: So wrong... UDP over NAT is certainly possible: the router keeps track of UPD connections with tuples of source & destination addresses & ports. The only problem with UDP is that is does not have a properly defined 'close' state, so after a while a router will have to purge old NAT entries for UDP that haven't seen traffic in a while. How long that is, depends on the router.

Comment: UDP does not have an 'open' or 'close' state.  That makes no sense.  Static rules (i.e. hole punching) is the only way to traverse NAT by UDP.  Do a google search (or even better here's a link for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching ).  The source port can change with each packet in UDP, so the connections table would not be able to dynamically track UDP packets.